# tinyMCE and pasted plain text from notepad results in different markup

Tags: tinymce, umbraco

When pasting text into tiny mce I get various behaviours. In my sample notepad text file I have this text:

```
a
b

c
```

Pasted in various browsers results in the following:

chrome 20:

```
<pre>a<br />b<br /><br />c</pre>
```

IE 9:

```
<p>a<br />b</p>
<p>c</p>
```

Firefox 13:

```
<p>a<br />b<br /><br />c</p>
```

I'd like the behaviour of IE9 in all browsers. Anyone have any suggestions how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you click the `Paste as Plain Text` icon in the toolbar, you will end up with the markup from your IE9 example above for the other browsers as well.

You can try it here:

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

You can see that option is configured like so (it is the `pastetext` option):

```
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
```

See paste documentation here:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste

As a last resort, you could use the `preprocess` callback and manually set the flag within the editor, something like:

```
ed.pasteAsPlainText = true;
```

Look around line 74 here:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/paste/editor_plugin_src.js

Comment: Probably there is a way, check the paste plugin doc here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:paste

Comment: thanks, Also: do you know for which versions this is effective? not sure I can upgrade umbraco's tinymce version.

Comment: There has been some form of that functionality for years now but has undergone a lot of changes along the way and had bugs in various versions...

Comment: sweet , thanks david, I'm now stuck trying to integrate you suggestion into the umbraco CMS :-\